# is there anyway to notify user if there are new commits in particular path in github

Tags: email, github, notifications, github-actions

i have a Github repo called myrepo
i want to get notified if someone pushes to this repo but only in certain path
eg :: myrepo/abc/def
i should get notified when someone changes only in this path

PS:: for entire repo I know we can set up GitHub notifications but is there any workarounds for only certain path

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to restrict webhooks or notifications to only operating on a specific path.

GitHub sends a *lot* of webhooks and notifications and receives a *lot* of pushes and data.  Filtering in this way means that the Git services need to be very intertwined with the notification services and that potentially a lot of data needs to be inspected.  For example, if I pushed a new copy of the Chromium repository or the Linux repository, this would involve a lot of commits needing to be traversed, which would very significantly delay the notifications and webhooks.  In order to make these operations (and hence your Actions, CI jobs, and Slack notifications) as fast as possible, they contain relatively few filtering capabilities.

If you wanted to do this with GitHub Actions, however, you could.  For example, the following shell snippet with return 0 (succeed) if there are any changes to the `Documentation` directory between `BASE` and `REV`:

```
$ git rev-list $BASE..$REV | xargs -I{} git diff --name-only {}^..{} | \
    grep '^Documentation'
```

You can add an action to operate on any push and send a notification in whatever way you desire, such as by sending an email, a Slack notification, or any other technique.